# Replay Tic Tac Toe

Tags: java, arrays, tic-tac-toe

I am writing a Tic Tac Toe game and need to ask if the user wants to play again, (y/n). I have the game working, I'm just not sure how to loop it if the user hits y, and/or terminate it if the user hits n. I've tried several different things but can't seem to figure any of them out, so this is just my working code posted. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment7 {

    public static int row, col;
    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static char[][] board = new char[3][3];
    public static char turn = 'X';
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*create for-loop
     * 9 empty spots, 3x3
         */

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                board[i][j] = '_';
            }
        }
        Play();
    }

    public static void Play() {
        //find if game over
        boolean playing = true;
        PrintBoard();

        while (playing) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a row, then a column: ");
            //make row next thing player types
            row = scan.nextInt() - 1;
            //same with column
            col = scan.nextInt() - 1;
            board[row][col] = turn;
            if (GameOver(row, col)) {
                playing = false;
                System.out.println("Game over! Player " + turn + " wins!");

            }
            PrintBoard();
            //switch players after entries
            if (turn == 'X') {
                turn = 'O';
            } else {
                turn = 'X';
            }
        }

    }

    public static void PrintBoard() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                //get dividers on left
                if (j == 0) {
                    System.out.print("| ");
                }
                // get dividers in all
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + " | ");
            }
        }
        //enter space after board
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static boolean GameOver(int rMove, int cMove) {
        // Check perpendicular victory
        if (board[0][cMove] == board[1][cMove]
                && board[0][cMove] == board[2][cMove]) {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[rMove][0] == board[rMove][1]
                && board[rMove][0] == board[rMove][2]) {
            return true;
        }
        // Check diagonal victory
        if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[0][0] == board[2][2]
                && board[1][1] != '_') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: `do { ... } while ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(input));` ?

Comment: What have you tried? What happened? You only show us the code of the game, which you said already works, so what's the point of showing it? Show us how you tried to ask the user if he wants to play again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a `do-while` loop and wrap it around your "game" code...

When the `Play` method returns, prompt the user if they want to play another game, loop until they answer with anything other then "Y", for example

```
String input = null;
do {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            board[i][j] = '_';
        }
    }
    Play();
    if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        scan.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.print("Do you want to play a game [Y/N]? ");
    input = scan.nextLine();
} while ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(input));
```

Comment: The program still terminates after a player wins. It won't allow me to enter "y" or "n".